# How do I play each channel separately of an audio file?

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I have a 4 channel ogg and wav file, I want to play each channel separately, like filtering. I have a stereo speaker what I want is when I pick a channel-1 speaker will only play the audio of channel 1.

I tried to dig in Naudio but can't figure it out for this purpose.

Any help would be so appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to play each channel separately with panning as well?

Comment: During playing audio, I just want to switch between channels like enable ch1, ch2 and disable ch3, ch4. Or disable three and enable one. Is it possible? I want to do it at runtime. Thanks.

Comment: It's possible.  You're going to want to mix your own output stream to have full control.  There's probably a good framework for doing this... I don't know of one offhand.

Comment: I hope I could find one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NAudio, you can make use of the `MultiplexingSampleProvider` to route specific inputs to outputs. Read more about it [here](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/handling-multi-channel-audio-in-naudio.html). This may meet your needs for multi-channel WAV playback.

NAudio does not currently include support for ogg playback, so you'd need to find an extension to do that (there are a few based on NVorbis).

Comment: I understand this part, but I encounter another problem. I have 6 channels wav,aac file. I tried to load them and play but failed. Can Naudio play multichannel audio?

Comment: what failed? What output device driver were you trying to use? Not all audio playback APIs support multi-channel audio, even if your soundcard has many outputs